# How much Swedish and Danish is used in The Square?

Tags: dialogue, the-square

I'm considering to go watch [The Square](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4995790/) with Danish subs, although I don't know Danish.

Is the film mostly in English?

Is the film comprehensible assuming I wouldn't understand the Swedish/Danish dialog?

Answer (score 1):

The movie has been nominated to an academy award in the Best Foreign Language Film category. [The rules](http://www.oscars.org/sites/oscars/files/90aa_rules.pdf) about foreign language film (rule 13) states

> **A. DEFINITION**
>
> A foreign language film is defined as a feature-length motion picture
>   (defined as over 40 minutes) produced outside the United States of
>   America with a **predominantly non-English dialogue** track. Animated and
>   documentary feature films are permitted.

So most of the movie is not in English. I haven't seen it, so I don't know if it's comprehensible without the Danish/Swedish parts.